# Get custom order item meta key and display in new column in WooCommerce orders view

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I am trying to create a new column in the WooCommerce orders table view. And populate it with the details of a custom meta key within the order. Only some orders will have this meta key value, only if the purchaser chooses a delivery date. The delivery date option is added to the order using the WooCommerce Product Add-Ons Ultimate plugin.

I have managed to create the new column but cannot seem to display the results of the custom Meta Key, which is **`_Choose Date`** every order returns the output "Meta key" is wrong or not found for the order items' which is what is shown if no value exists.

My code is here:

````
function custom_shop_order_column( $columns ) {
    // Add new columns
    $columns['delivery_date'] = __( 'Delivery Date', 'woocommerce' ); 
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column', 10, 1 );

//  Populate the Column
function custom_shop_order_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    // Get order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

    // Is a WC_Order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        // Initialize
         $delivery_date_arr = array();
        
        // Loop trough order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
            // Get meta, use the correct meta key!
            $delivery_date = $item->get_meta( '_Choose Date' );
            
            // NOT empty
            if ( ! empty ( $delivery_date ) ) {
                // Push to array
                $delivery_date_arr[] = $delivery_date;
            }
            
        }
        
        // Compare column name
        if ( $column == 'delivery_date' ) {
            // NOT empty
            if ( ! empty ( $delivery_date_arr ) ) {
                // Output
                echo '<ul>';
                echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $delivery_date_arr ) . '</li>';
                echo '</ul>';
            } else {
                // Output
                echo __( 'Meta key is wrong or not found for the order items', 'woocommerce' );
            }
        }
   
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_shop_order_list_column_content', 10, 2 );```
````

Comment: The meta key `_Choose Date` with the corresponding meta value should appear in admin single order pages on the order items … To be sure that you get the correct meta key, you should look in `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`database table. You could easily replace the plugin with hand coded custom fields, and you will not have this problem.

Comment: Ah, the Meta Key was wrong, looking in the database there were two values _Choose Date and _Choose Delivery Date. When initially doing this code I had completely the wrong meta key and when trying again today I looked in the DB table and found _Choose Date but I changed this field in the plugin recently to Choose Delivery Date which subsequently changed the Meta Key name...doh! Thanks, all works now.

Comment: I still added an answer with an improved code version…

Answer (score 1):

Looking to `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` database table allowed you to get the correct meta key, here is an improved version code, that I already made:

```php
// Add new columns
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column', 10, 1 );
function custom_shop_order_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['delivery_date'] = __( 'Delivery Date', 'woocommerce' ); 
    return $columns;
}

//  Populate the Column
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_shop_order_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_shop_order_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    if ( $column === 'delivery_date' ) {
        global $the_order; // The order object
    
        $delivery_dates_html = ''; // Initialize

        // Loop trough order items
        foreach ( $the_order->get_items() as  $item ) {
            // Get meta, use the correct meta key!
            if ( $delivery_date = $item->get_meta( '_Choose Delivery Date' ) ) {
                $delivery_dates_html .= '<li>' . $delivery_date . '</li>';
            }
        }
        
        if (! empty( $delivery_dates_html ) > 0 ) {
            echo '<ul>' . $delivery_dates_html . '</ul>';
        } else {
            _e("No date", "woocommerce");
        }
    }
}
```

It should even better work.

Comment: Great thanks, there is the underscore missing from the metakey _Choose Delivery Date, but other than that all good.